# How to fix Error: No valid exports main found for ‘web-application/node_modules/uuid'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a second data-access-layer for my web-app using sequelize. I get this error when i require the module 'sequelize'.

I have tried to change the node version to 4 different ones but still i do not get rid of the error.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize') // the error occur here
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:') 

//this is how i register the awilix container
container.register({ 
    SQLiteDb: awilix.asValue(require('./data-access-layer-sequelize/SQLiteDb'))
})

//this is how the functions are exported
module.exports = function({ SQLiteDb }){
return {
    getAllPosts: function(club, callback) {
        SQLiteDb.findAll({ where: { club }, raw: true })
            .then(posts => callback([], posts))
            .catch(error => callback(['internalError'], null))

    }
}
```

[image: The error message]

[image: Package-lock.json]

[image: Package.json]

Comment: Please consider adding your code here instead of putting them in images.

Comment: what is your solution ?

Comment: Still stuck with the problem...